# Get the number before last comma in string

Tags: php

I have a string with numbers with variable digits, separated by commas:

```
$num = 15.514,6.23,9.15
```

I'm able to get the last value using this:

```
$last = substr($num, strrpos($num, ",") + 1); // 9.15
```

How can I get the number before the last comma (6.23)? The numbers can vary in size, so I have to make sure it gets the number no matter how many digits it have.

Comment: `$arr = explode(',', $num);
    $val = $arr[count($arr)-2]];`

Answer (score 0):

```
$split = explode(',', $num); // splits the string at each comma

// first option
$secondLast = $split[count($split) - 2];

// second option
end($split); // gets the pointer to the last array element
$secondLast = prev($split); // moves the pointer back one entry
```

There's not really a big speed difference so you can use the one you like more.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want with a regex that uses the natural greediness of quantifiers to reach the last comma:

```
$result = preg_replace('~.*(?<![^,])([^,]*),.*~', '$1', $str);
```

*(in short: capture the last part of the string that isn't preceded by a character that is **not** a comma until the last comma, and remove all around)*

but since the delimiter is a fixed string, a simple `explode` should suffice or why not `str_getcsv` that is designed for comma separated values:

```
$parts = str_getcsv($str);
array_pop($parts);
$result = end($parts);
```